# Coordinate vs position

Tags: math, naming

```
struct Point2D
{
  int x;
  int y;
};
```

There is a 2D tile-based map.
How to name variable of type Point2D which represents coordinates of specific tile?

```
Point2D tilePosition;
```

or

```
Point2D tileCoordinate;
```

I have problem in understanding difference between coordinate and position.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Coordinate system is just a way to identify position, I prefer `tilePosition`. IMHO, naming is supposed to indicate the meaning of the variable, not what the inside structure is.